# Using http request output var from function into other scripts

Tags: python, function

Since i have a script that uses a lot of http requests, i decided to create a function to do that ( instead having the same block of code over, and over... ). But the problem im facing, is how i can return the html output from file_a.py to file_b.py? Since i need the output to parse some results?

file_a.py

```
def invokeServer(proxyUser,proxyPass,proxyHost,iserver,isService,login,password):

  proxy_auth = "http://"+proxyUser+":"+proxyPass+"@"+proxyHost
  proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({"http": proxy_auth})
  opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy_handler)
  opener = urllib2.build_opener()
  urllib2.install_opener(opener)
  request = urllib2.Request("http://"+iserver+""+isService)
  base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % (login, password)).replace('\n', '')
  request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
  response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
  html= response.read()
  return html
```

file_b.py

```
from file_a import invokeServer
invokeServer(proxyUser,proxyPass,proxyHost,iserver,isService,login,password)

# From this line bellow, i need to use the html result from file_a.py
doc = LH.fromstring(html) 
LE.strip_tags(doc,'b')
data_list = doc.xpath("//td[text()='triggerNameList']/following-sibling::*")[0]
triggerName = data_list.xpath("//td[text()='triggerName']/following-sibling::*/text()")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

store it in a variable:

```
html = invokeServer(...
```